# How to convert 2 lists into a dictionary WITH Column headers in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-zip

Although this seems a popular question, mine is different. I need the resulting dictionary to have headers:

Here's what Im doing:

```
list1 = [code_a, code_b, code_c]
list2 = [name_a, name_b, name_c]
```

to make this into a dictionary - we can use the zip function:

```
res = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

This will indeed produce for me a dictionary, and if I were to print out the result, I'd get a dictionary - **but without headers**.

I need headers - such that the dictionary appears as:

```
combined_list = {'Code': code_a, 'Name': name_a, 'Code': code_b, 'Name': name_b, 'Code': code_c, 'Name': name_c}
```

I have tried so many things, but none seem to work, and I really couldn't find this in stack overflow.

Comment: but how `Code` key can come twice in your dictionary ?

Comment: you can't get the exact result you want, because you'd have multiple values for the same keys. Would you be cool with having a list or set containing many dictionaries with those labels/values?
You probably want to use something like the pandas library.

Comment: Sure @Byron. Let me have what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i'm not very skilled at coding but in your combined_list you have duplicate keys so your goal isn't possible. I don't know what you're doing but i guess you could use a 2D datastructure. something like this:

```
combined_list = [('code_a', 'name_a'), ('code_b', 'name_b'), ('code_c', 'name_c')]
```

you cold generate it like this:

```
list1 = ["code_a", "code_b", "code_c"]
list2 = ["name_a","name_b", "name_c"]
combined_list = list(zip(list1, list2)))
```